# npm install error import sys; print "%s.%s.%s"

Tags: python, node.js

When I run npm install I get the following error, and I couldn't fix it.

I tried : npm install -g windows-build-tools and it also did not fixed this error

```
   ERR! configure error
ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % 
  sys.v
ion_info[:3];
 ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
 ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
 ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I downgraded the node version to 14 and it worked.

Steps: With NVM: (node version manager)

1. Install nvm (node version manager)

> ```
> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
> ```

2. Install node version 14

> nvm install 14

3. Use node version 1

> nvm use 14

Steps for Brew: If you use HomeBrew:

```
brew install node@14 
brew unlink node  
brew link --overwrite node@14
```

Answer (score -2):

Had encountered such error with some third-party repos - `npm install` failed identical way you mentioned.
I backed up package.json devDependencies section, cleaned it, then ran `npm install` for each package mentioned which solved the problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the solution you provide. As its described now its lacking details on what to do exactly.

Comment: I don't think it's lacking any important details especially while the question was vague but I'll try to clarify it just for you:

1. find dependencies or devDependencies section in package.json
2. copy a list of modules to a notepad
3. clear the section, save the file
4. run npm install for each module previously listed to update dependencies